# Trouble with Eclipse while opening rptdesign

Tags: eclipse, exception, nullpointerexception, birt

I'm having some problems when I'm trying to open a rptdesign. The name of the file doesn't load, it stays all blank and when I close the file the Eclipses throw a null pointer exception. I'm using eclipse.buildId=4.4.1 (Luna) and java.version=1.7.0_75. Anyone know how to solve it?

Follow the stack trace:

```
Message: Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt"

Stack Trace: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.EditorInputPropertyTester.test(EditorInputPropertyTester.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.Property.test(Property.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.TestExpression.evaluate(TestExpression.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateAnd(CompositeExpression.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.WithExpression.evaluate(WithExpression.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.CompositeExpression.evaluateOr(CompositeExpression.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.OrExpression.evaluate(OrExpression.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.expressions.ReferenceExpression.evaluate(ReferenceExpression.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.evaluate(EvaluationReference.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationReference.changed(EvaluationReference.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService$1.changed(EvaluationService.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activate(EclipseContext.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.activateBranch(EclipseContext.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener$1.run(ShellActivationListener.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.processWindow(ShellActivationListener.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.ShellActivationListener.handleEvent(ShellActivationListener.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1060)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1666)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2151)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4607)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Do you have the file available for download?

Answer (score 0):

Try switch to a new workspace should help you. Eclipse has almost no settings that are stored outside your workspace.

if it does not work, I advise you to open your file with a text editor "notpad ++ for example" and see the version of birt used in the development  (see  tag), download and use it to open your file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.12" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 2.2.0.qualifier Build &lt;@BUILD@></property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
........
```